# how to add conditional text without forcing it? [101, pdf form]

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

Just tried to play around with pdf forms (using foxit phantom) and was able to figure some basics for calculations with Javascript, for what I needed (really simple form).
But this issue I don't know how to solve, nor how to search for answers properly, so any help/directions would be welcome.
I'm trying something like this as a 'calculation' on a field:

```
var x=this.getField ("TextField1");

var y=this.getField ("NumberField1");

var z=this.getField ("NumberField2");

if (x.value = "A") {z.value=(50+y.value);}

else if (x.value = "B","C") {z.value=(100+y.value);}

else if (x.value = "D") {z.value=(200+y.value);}

else {z.value="Type an appropriate letter on TextField1"}
```

but when I enter it, it forces the TextField1 to be filled with "A" (or whatever I write on the first condition. The numeric sum is added correctly (for "A", 50+y) but if I try to type some other letter on `TextField1`, it erases and returns "A", forcing it to be the only thing on that field.
Even after switching A to B on the first conditional, it does change to a forced "B" on the textfield1 but then the numerical sum is not adjusted to `(100+y)`, but that seems to be yet another error due to my nonexistent experience with code past some c++...

The idea is to add into NumberField2 according to what the user types on `TextField1` but the code forces the text into it.

This is probably absolutely trivial and sorry if this site is not the medium for such things, but I really had no idea what to search for on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you have to use == for comparision, a singe = is an assign.
So what you do is to always set TextField1.value to "A"

try if (x.value == "A") {z.value=(50+y.value);}

(the same applies to the other conditions as well)

```
var x=this.getField ("TextField1");
var y=this.getField ("NumberField1");
var z=this.getField ("NumberField2");

if (x.value == "A") {z.value=(50+y.value);}
else if ((x.value == "B") || (x.value == "C")) {z.value=(100+y.value);}
else if (x.value == "D") {z.value=(200+y.value);}
else {z.value="Type an appropriate letter on TextField1"}
```

Comment: It worked, I think. It doesn't force the text anymore but it simply disregards what I type in textfield and NumberField2 always returns 50+y, no matter what is typed. Can you see where else the code is wrong? thanks!

Comment: th second else if should triggger if value is B or C, right?
I adjusted the code in my answer.

Comment: The solution does indeed work, and there is nothing against it, and I guess it is some kind of personal preference… Why not use switch… instead of a string of else…if?

Comment: you are right - switch is a the better solution from a readability stanadpoint for sure. I just wanted to stick to his code sample for transparency.